# How "shall" has been used?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, modal-verbs

What would entire dialogue mean if shall is replaced by will,would,can,could? How to use this specific word-shall?

[image]

> The human whose name is written in this notebook **shall** die.

What does this dialogue mean?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, shall means will.
"The human whose name is written in this notebook *will* die" also works.